# Merging two arrays in Scala

Tags: scala

My requirement is that :

```
arr1 : Array[(String, String)] = Array((bangalore,Kanata),  (kannur,Kerala)) 
arr2 : Array[(String, String)] = Array((001,anup), (002,sithu))
```

should give me

```
Array((001,anup,bangalore,Krnata), (002,sithu,kannur,Kerala))
```

I tried this :

```
val arr3 = arr2.map(field=>(field,arr1))
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Obviously `map` won't work because that iterates the items of the collection. If you want to purely append collections look at https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-merging-two-arrays-arraybuffers-joining

Comment: It looks like you actually want to `zip` the two arrays. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-merge-sequential-collection-pairs-zip-unzip-scala-cookbook

Answer (score 2):

[@nicodp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955069/1376448) addressed your question very nicely. `zip` and then `map` will give you the resultant array.

> Recall that if one list is larger than the other, its remaining elements are ignored. 
>   My attempt tries to address this:

Consider:

```
val arr1 =  Array(("bangalore","Kanata"),  ("kannur","Kerala"))

val arr2 = Array(("001","anup", "ramakrishan"), ("002","sithu", "bhattacharya"))
```

`zip` and mapping on tuples will give the result as:

```
arr1.zip(arr2).map(field => (field._1._1, field._1._2, field._2._1, field._2._2))
Array[(String, String, String, String)] = Array((bangalore,Kanata,001,anup), (kannur,Kerala,002,sithu)) 
// This ignores the last field of arr2
```

While mapping, you can convert the tuple in iterator and get a list from it. This will enable you to not keep a track of `Tuple2` or `Tuple3`

```
arr1.zip(arr2).map{ case(k,v) => List(k.productIterator.toList, v.productIterator.toList).flatten }
// Array[List[Any]] = Array(List(bangalore, Kanata, 001, anup, ramakrishan), List(kannur, Kerala, 002, sithu, bhattacharya))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `zip` followed by a `map`:

```
scala> val arr1 = Array((1,2),(3,4))
arr1: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,4))

scala> val arr2 = Array((5,6),(7,8))
arr2: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((5,6), (7,8))

scala> arr1.zip(arr2).map(field => (field._1._1, field._1._2, field._2._1, field._2._2))
res1: Array[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Array((1,2,5,6), (3,4,7,8))
```

The `map` acts as a flatten for tuples, that is, takes things of type `((A, B), (C, D))` and maps them to `(A, B, C, D)`.

What `zip` does is... meh, let's see its type:

```
def zip[B](that: GenIterable[B]): List[(A, B)]
```

So, from there, we can argue that it takes an iterable collection (which can be another list) and returns a list which is the combination of the corresponding elements of both `this: List[A]` and `that: List[B]` lists. Recall that if one list is larger than the other, its remaining elements are ignored. You can dig more about list functions in the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the cleanes solution is using the zip method from collections

```
val arr1 = Array(("bangalore","Kanata"),  ("kannur","Kerala"))
val arr2 = Array(("001","anup"), ("002","sithu"))

arr1.zip(arr2).foldLeft(List.empty[Any]) {
  case (acc, (a, b)) => acc ::: List(a.productIterator.toList ++ b.productIterator.toList)
}
```